# Alternative to load-on-startup Servlets for bootstrapping methods in an webapp

Tags: java, scala, web-applications

I am looking for a simple library for bootstrapping code in my webapp right at startup.

I am aware that this could be done by having a servlet with load-on-startup param set. But I would like something much cleaner and simpler.
Something as simple as an annotation which i could put in my java or scala methods.

```
@Boot
def myBootMethod() = {}
```

Also i do not want heavyweight libraries like spring etc which does much more than that. I just wanna bootstrap stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a ServletContextListener and configure it in your web.xml or using the appropriate annotations.

In the ServletContextListener, you can implement two methods:

`public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e)` is invoked when the web application is deployed.

`public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e)` is invoked when the web application is undeployed. Note that this method may not be invoked, if the servlet container is stopped in a non-regular way.